# Change background color of parent component from child component based on child state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a spinner in a component that is in a div of a parent layout container. In my child container, I have a victory chart draw when the data loads. I have the spinner run until the ajax gets the data and sets the state. I want to change the background color of the parent component div based upon the state so that the spinner is on a different color background than the chart.

In my chart component it works like this:

```
if(this.state.data){
        return (
            <div className="chart">
              ...
            </div>
          }else {
            return <div class="spinner></div>
          }
```

That all works fine, but what I also want to do is set the background color of the parent div using something like:

```
if(this.state.data) {
  this.props.setParentBackgroundColor("#fff")
```

}

Even if I create a prop and pass in a function, it doesn't seem to set the background color of the parent. Is there a way to do that based on the component rather than through an onclick or some user event?

Here is another version of a child component switching slides, at the forth slide I want to change the parent background:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AdminLoginsChart } from './admin-logins-chart';

export class Slides extends Component {
render(){
if(this.props.slideNum === 0) {
    return (
        //<div>Slide 0</div>
        <AdminLoginsChart />
    );
} else if (this.props.slideNum === 1) {
    return <div>Slide 1</div>;
} else if (this.props.slideNum === 2) {
    return <div>Slide 2</div>
} else {
    this.props.ChangeParentStyle("fff"); // change the parent here
    return <div>Out of slides</div>;
}
};
}

// Parent Component has this:

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        interval: 8000,
        slideNum: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc'
    };
}

ChangeParentStyle = (backgroundColor)=> {
    this.setState({
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor
    })
}

slide = () => {

        //increase by num 1, reset to 0 at 4
        if (this.state.slideNum === 0) {
            //slide 0;
            console.log("slide 0");
        } else if (this.state.slideNum === 1) {
            //slide 1;
            console.log("slide 1");
            this.setState({slideNum: 1})

        } else if (this.state.slideNum === 2) {
            //slide 2;
            console.log("slide 2");
            this.setState({slideNum: 2})
        }
        this.setState({slideNum :(this.state.slideNum + 1) % 4});

        //return this.state.slideNum;
    }


stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalrefreshId);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalrefreshId = window.setInterval(this.slide, this.state.interval);
}
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    </div>
      <Chart style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}} >
            <Slides slideNum={this.state.slideNum} ChangeParentStyle={this.ChangeParentStyle.bind(this)}/>
          {/*<AdminLoginsChart data={this.state.data}/>*/}

      </Chart >


  </div>
);
```

Comment: What does "Even if I create a prop and pass in a function, it doesn't seem to set the background color of the parent." mean? Can you post what `setParentBackgroundColor` does? Sounds like you have the right approach, create function in parent component that updates the style of the parent component and pass that function down as a prop to the child. I need to see more code to understand your problem. Can you post the full code for the Parent and Child?

Comment: OK, thanks for helping. I added more code to my original post. Does it make sense? There is more going on than just the chart component. I also want to do the same when the slides run out.

Comment: In this example, you're missing the `#` in front of the hex code you are passing to `ChangeParentStyle` in the `Slides` component. Other than that, your code looks good.

Comment: I'm still having an issue setting state in the parent component to change the background color. It seems to set off a rendering of parent to child loop that is endless and causes a memory overflow  I've tried adding the call to ChangeParentStyle in the ComponentDidUpdate event, but I get this: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Here is a jsbin showing what I am trying to do. When it gets to slide 3 it should change the parent background color. https://jsbin.com/mahocuq/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the JSBin, I think I found your problem:

This method in the `Slide` component:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
        if(this.props.slideNum === 2){
            this.changeStyle("#fff")
        }    
}
```

This method will fire anytime the component gets new props. You are calling `changeStyle` which calls `ChangeParentStyle` which then changes `this.state.background` and passes that down as a new prop to the `Slide` component. The slide component then sees that a new prop is passed down, then it calls the function again and repeats over and over. You need to do a check against the background in your `componentWillUpdate` method.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        if(this.props.slideNum === 2 && this.props.background !== nextProps.background){
            this.changeStyle("#fff")
        }    
}
```

So now, the function will only try to update the background color if the colors don't match. I'm not sure what the actual logic should be, but this should help you get it working.